# Alternative for SET in PYTHON

Tags: python, set

When I try to solve a problem from hackers rank, ([problem link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-lists/problem)).
I have a  problem with set. In python, set doesn't support repetition. So, I need alternative for it. The code I used:

```
n = int(input())
global rule_set, semifinal_list, final_list, name
rule_set = {}
semifinal_list = []
final_list = []
name = []

for _ in range(n):
    rule,*no = input().split()
    name.append(rule)
    condition = list(map(int, no))
    rule_set[rule] = condition

def cal(n):
    for i in name:
        print(name)
        if (i == "insert"):
            insert = rule_set["insert"]
            semifinal_list.insert(insert[0],insert[1])
            print(semifinal_list)

        elif(i == "append"):
            append = rule_set["append"]
            semifinal_list.append(append)

        elif(i == "remove"):
            remove = rule_set["remove"]
            semifinal_list.remove(remove)

        elif(i == "pop"):
            pop = rule_set[pop]
            semifinal_list.pop(pop)
        
        elif(i == "sort"):
            semifinal_list.sort()
        
        elif(i == "reverse"):
            semifinal_list.reverse

        elif(i == "print"):
            def removenesting(semifinal_list):
                for i in semifinal_list:
                    if (type(i) == list):
                        removenesting(i)
                    else:
                        final_list.append(i)
            removenesting(semifinal_list)
            print(final_list)

cal(n)
```

Here, `rule_set{}` is the set that I have a problem with. I need to give several inputs like

```
12
insert 0 5
insert 1 10
insert 0 6
print
remove 6
append 9
append 1
sort
print
pop
reverse
print
```

, but the set doesn't support repetition. I need an alternative for this. Even if you know any other simple way to solve this problem replay that too with a full explanation.

Comment: The question is about **Lists**. So try using a list instead of a set, and then proceed with what you were doing initially because lists allow repetition of data in them.

Comment: `if` statements in Python do not use enclosing parentheses.  That habit comes from C.

Comment: So you basically give commands to the program like ```insert```, or ```append```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So taking a look at the question and your solution, it looks like it can be shortened down quite a bit.
Here's my solution:

```py
n = int(input())
l = []
for i in range(n):
    s = input().split(" ")
    ls = s[0]
    num = s[1:]
    if ls != "print":
        ls += "("+ ",".join(num) +")"
        eval("l."+ls)
    else:
        print(l)
```

P.s. I don't use HackerRank, so I don't know whether it runs on all conditions, but it surely does on the base case.

Explanation:

**.join()** concatenates the ls with an opening parenthesis "(", joins the arguments together with a comma and then concatenates a closing parenthesis.

**eval** parses the expression passed to this method and runs it. Here, it takes the list `l` and adds the function that needs to be performed.
For eg:

append 6:
`eval("l." + ls)` would make this `eval("l." + "append")` since `ls` is append in this case, and the final output of `eval` is `l.append` which performs its respective calculation.

Comment: I am new to Coding can you explain it briefly

Comment: @GoAmeer030 first you take input for ```n```, which denotes number of commands. ```input``` by default takes a string so we need to explicitly convert it to int hence the ```int(input())```. Then we create an empty list: ```l = []```. Then we run the for loop for the number of commands ```n``` initially taken as input. We again take input for the calculations to be performed and split with ```.split(" ")```. This will split the input based on the input provided as argument. In this case, a space. Then we store the split input into 2 variables ```ls``` and ```num```.

Comment: @GoAmeer030 ```ls``` has the the first data of the split input, for eg: for the input **append 6**, ```ls = "append"``` and ```num = 6```. Finally we check if ```ls``` is not "print" and perform the operation already explained. And if it is "print", then we print the output.

Comment: I have heard that ```eval``` is dangerous

Comment: @Sanskar Singh Thank you for your explanation and the time. but except line 8 and 9, I understand other things. So, please explain those two lines a little much clearly.

Comment: Let's take an example: **append 6**. So we know that ```ls = "append"``` and ```num = 6``` as already explained. ```ls += "("+ ",".join(num) +")"``` This over here evaluates to -> ```append(6)```. So basically, ```ls = "append(6)"```. Now for ```eval("l."+ls)```, we already have value of ```ls```. So the following code becomes -> ```eval("l."+"append(6)")```, which when concatenated with "+" gives ```eval("l.append(6)")```. So what ```eval``` does is, it performs the function provided as arguments. Like over here, it will append 6 to the list ```l```.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this simple piece of code:

```
n=int(input("Enter the number of commands: "))
total_list=[]

for i in range(n):
    x=input("Enter a command: ").split()
    
    #==== .lower() converts it into lower case.

    if x[0].lower()=="append":                                      #=== Split gives a list, check if the first element in lower case is equal to the parameter
        total_list.append(x[1])                                     #== Add the second element to list.
        print(f"Appended {x[1]} to the list.")


    elif x[0].lower()=="print":                                     #=== Split gives a list, check if the first element in lower case is equal to the parameter
        print(total_list)


    elif x[0].lower()=="insert":                                    #=== Split gives a list, check if the first element in lower case is equal to the parameter
        try:
            total_list.insert(int(x[1]),x[2])                       #=== Insert takes 1: integer as the index and 2: the element
            print(f"Inserted {x[2]} at index {x[1]}.") 
        except IndexError:                                          #=== If something is missing
            print(f"Could not insert as no value was provided.")


    elif x[0].lower()=="remove":                                    #=== Split gives a list, check if the first element in lower case is equal to the parameter
        try:
            total_list.remove(x[1])                                 #=== Remove the second element
            print(f"Removed {x[1]} from the list.")
        except Exception:                                           #=== If element is absent
            print(f"Could not remove as the element is not present")


    elif x[0].lower()=="sort":                                      #=== Split gives a list, check if the first element in lower case is equal to the parameter
        try:
            total_list=[int(y) for y in total_list]                 #== Convert everything to integer. 
            total_list.sort()                                       #=== Sort the list
            total_list=[str(y) for y in total_list]                 #=== Convert everything to string
        except Exception:                                           #=== If exception occurs
            total_list.sort()                                       #=== Just sort the list
        print("List sorted successfully.")


    elif x[0].lower()=="pop":                                       #=== Split gives a list, check if the first element in lower case is equal to the parameter
        total_list.pop()                                            #=== Remove the last element
        print("Removed the last element from the list.")


    elif x[0].lower()=="reverse":                                   #=== Split gives a list, check if the first element in lower case is equal to the parameter
        total_list.reverse()                                        #=== Reverse the list
        print("List reversed successfully.")


    else:
        print(f"Invalid command provided: {x[0]}")
```